# Eclipse RCP avoid singletons

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

What is the simplest way to have some sort of DI in RCP application? 
I need to register dependencies and use them in different parts of application: wizards, dialogs, properties pages, etc.

**What I have:** a product with bunch of plugins.

**What I need:** at start of Eclipse RCP product I need to read some files, keep this data in memory and make it accesible to different UI elements(among different plugins) without using of singletons.

I cant pass this data in constructors when creating consumers, because consumers are UI elements which often created by RCP platform and I dont have direct access for their creation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Eclipse 4.3 supports DI. This works best for a RCP created as a pure Eclipse 4 application which does not use Eclipse 3 compatibility code ('e4' mode). Objects which are defined in the new application model are created using DI, but it is also possible to create other objects (dialogs for example) using injection.

For an introduction to Eclipse 4 RCP see http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseRCP/article.html

For an Eclipse 3 application a part can get the Eclipse Context needed for injection using

```
IWorkbenchPartSite site = part.getSite();
IEclipseContext parentContext = (IEclipseContext) site.getService(IEclipseContext.class);
```

Use `org.eclipse.e4.core.contexts.ContextInjectionFactory` for injection.

Comment: Great. Actually, my app is working on Eclipse 4.3 currently, but all code was written for Eclipse 3.5. Can I register my own components in context on this case?

Answer (score 0):

Or, if you are still using an Eclipse 3 application, you can use the Eclipse Plugin Registry to define extension points and extensions. This also amounts to Dependency Injection, without the injection :-)